# Click on a text with role button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape some website which includes "Load more" text. Down you can see the whole html code.
I tried many solutions but nothing works.
I am using Python and Selenium webdriver. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

HTML code:

```
<td class="MuiTableCell-root-565 MuiTableCell-body-567 MuiTableCell-paddingNone-571" colspan="5">
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-2050 MuiButton-root-2023 MuiButton-text-2025 MuiButton-textPrimary-2026" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="width:100%;padding:16px;text-align:center">
<span class="MuiButton-label-2024"><span>Load mor...</span>
</span>
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-2051"></span>
</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Please make sure your code block is formatted correctly so it is visible in your post, and that the HTML code itself is both valid and formatted

Answer (score 0):

Install Selenium IDE using Chrome web browser

Press Record

Click about

The code will be generated for you.

Should give you what you need as a starter for 10